# 403 Forbidden Error When Setting Google Drive File Permissions via FastAPI

Tags: python, permissions, google-drive-api, fastapi, http-status-code-403

I am building an application using FastAPI that downloads images from URLs, zips them, and uploads the zip file to Google Drive using the Google Drive API. The application should then set the file permissions to make it publicly accessible. However, I encounter a 403 Forbidden error when attempting to set the file permissions.

Here's the simplified version of my code:

```
`from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Query
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
# Assuming you might still want to use requests for other purposes, keeping it imported
import requests
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseUpload
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from io import BytesIO
import os
import tempfile
import base64
import zipfile

app = FastAPI()

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'triple-water-379900-cd410b5aff31.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
BING_API_KEY = 'd7325b31eb1845b7940decf84ba56e13'  # If you plan to use Bing Image Search API directly


def build_drive_service():
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)
    return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

def get_image_urls_for_query(query, limit=5):
    search_url = "https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/images/search"
    headers = {"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": BING_API_KEY}
    params = {"q": query, "count": limit}
    response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()
    search_results = response.json()
    return [img["contentUrl"] for img in search_results["value"]]

def download_image_in_memory(image_url):
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'
    }
    response = requests.get(image_url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()  # Ensure the request was successful
    return BytesIO(response.content)


def upload_file_to_drive(service, file_name, file_content, mime_type='image/jpeg'):
    file_metadata = {'name': file_name}
    media = MediaIoBaseUpload(file_content, mimetype=mime_type, resumable=True)
    try:
        file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
        # Set the file to be publicly readable
        permission = {
            'type': 'anyone',
            'role': 'reader',
        }
        service.permissions().create(fileId=file.get('id'), body=permission).execute()
        return f"https://drive.google.com/uc?id={file.get('id')}"
    except HttpError as error:
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Failed to upload {file_name}: {str(error)}")




@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return HTMLResponse(content="<h1>Image Uploader to Google Drive</h1>")

@app.post("/download-images/")
async def download_images(query: str = Query(..., description="The search query for downloading images"), 
                          limit: int = Query(1, description="The number of images to download")):
    image_urls = get_image_urls_for_query(query, limit)

    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as temp_dir:
        zip_filename = os.path.join(temp_dir, "images.zip")
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, 'w') as zipf:
            for i, image_url in enumerate(image_urls, start=1):
                try:
                    image_content = requests.get(image_url).content
                    image_name = f"image_{i}.jpg"
                    image_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, image_name)
                    with open(image_path, 'wb') as image_file:
                        image_file.write(image_content)
                    zipf.write(image_path, arcname=image_name)
                except Exception as e:
                    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Failed to download {image_url}: {str(e)}")
        
        service = build_drive_service()
        file_metadata = {'name': 'images.zip'}
        media = MediaFileUpload(zip_filename, mimetype='application/zip')
        file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
        drive_url = f"https://drive.google.com/uc?id={file.get('id')}"
        return {"message": "Zip file uploaded successfully.", "url": drive_url}
```

The file uploads successfully, but when setting the permissions, I receive the following error:
HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions

I've ensured that the Google Drive API is enabled and the service account has the necessary permissions. I've also tried adding a User-Agent header to my requests but still encounter the same issue.

Question:

How can I resolve the 403 Forbidden error when setting Google Drive file permissions through my FastAPI application?
Is there any additional configuration or scope I need to include to allow my service account to change file permissions?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

i tried using chatgpt to fix it and it can't knowing why it shows the error

Comment: If you can upload the file without issues, but then get a 403, then something is off with the service account's permissions.